# Matching exact fields

Tags: arrays, regex, perl

I have a question.

I am working with very large list data and I need to omit anything in a certain field with the quantity of exactly '0'.  My problem is, and you will obviously see why, is I am also omitting other things that contain `'0'`, i.e. `100, 101`, pretty much anything that contains a `0` as well as the exact value of `0`.

Example Table:

```
ID   Name  Food   quantity   price
1   Josh   hotdog   1   5.00
2   Josh   hotdog   100   5.0
3   Josh   hotdog   101   5.00
4   Josh   hotdog   0   5.00
5   Josh   hotdog   1   5.00
```

The row I would like to omit has the `'ID'` number `'4'`.  I do not need any rows with a quantity of `0`.
The code I have used is a command prompt one-liner I apply to batch files.  It looks like this.

```
perl i.bak -aF\t -ne "print if $F[3] =~ "/[0]/" file.txt.
```

Now I know this will not work because the character class randomizes `'0'`.  In other words it is saying "if" there is a '0' anywhere in that field print it(or "unless", I have "if" on my one liner this time to see the results).

Just looking for an exact match of `'0'` and wondering if that is possible with the method I am using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
perl i.bak -aF\t -ne "print if $F[3] =~ "/[0]/" file.txt.
```

to

```
perl i.bak -aF\t -ne 'print if $F[3] ne "0"' file.txt
```

or

```
perl i.bak -aF\t -ne 'print if $F[3] != 0' file.txt
```

or

```
perl i.bak -aF\t -ne 'print if $F[3] !~ m/^0$/' file.txt
```

and try again.

Your `$F[3] =~ /[0]/` will be true if `$F[3]` includes character `0`.

Comment: perfect solution.  I see that the modified command now takes '0' as literal instead of including the character '0' like you said.  On this note, is there anyway to include another element of my array, say if I wanted to omit where [3] and [4] both contain the value of '0'?

Comment: @joshE Yes, you just need a more complex `if` condition, like `... if ($F[3] != 0 and $F[4] != 0)`.

Comment: Perfect!  Opens up a lot of doors.  Kind of an sql style perl one-liner that allows you to manage data from the cmd.

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need regex for this case, the simplest way is

```
perl i.bak -aF\t -ne "print if $F[3] ne q{0} " file.txt

Output:
ID      Name    Food    quantity        price
1       Josh    hotdog  1       5.00
2       Josh    hotdog  100     5.0
3       Josh    hotdog  101     5.00
5       Josh    hotdog  1       5.00
```

**Edit:** If you want to use the regex, then you need to cut on new line not on tab

```
perl i.bak -aF\n -ne "print if $F[0] !~ /\s+0\s*/" file.txt
```

or

```
perl i.bak -aF\n -ne "print unless $F[0] =~ /\s+0\s*/" file.txt

Output:
ID      Name    Food    quantity        price
1       Josh    hotdog  1       5.00
2       Josh    hotdog  100     5.0
3       Josh    hotdog  101     5.00
5       Josh    hotdog  1       5.00
```